# Is List.isEmpty() necessary before a DML?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, dml

After working on many different code bases in Salesforce, I noticed that almost all developers check if a list is empty before doing a DML in order to avoid the unnecessary DML statement.

Here's an example:

```
if(!accountList.isEmpty()) {
    update accountList;
}
```

However, I tried running the code below in Execute Anonymous:

```
Account[] accounts = new Account[]{};
update accounts;
System.debug(Limits.getDmlRows()); // Returns Zero
System.debug(Limits.getDmlStatements()); // Returns Zero
System.debug(Limits.getLimitDmlRows()); // Returns 10,000
System.debug(Limits.getLimitDmlStatements()); // Returns 150
```

Based on the results, I came to the conclusion that checking if a list is empty or not is unnecessary when it comes to Salesforce limits. It also does not fire any triggers, flows etc. on the Account object.

I guess the question is: Is there any other reasons to do the check before a DML or is this common trap we all fell into?

Comment: It is unnecessary as you have found.

Comment: It's only our fourth highest voted question on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there is zero benefit in doing an empty check on a list before performing DML on it.

There is some indication that Salesforce used to count the DML statement against you when the list was empty, but digging up information on *when* that was the case (or when it changed) has proven difficult. I can only say that this hasn't been a concern since at least late 2013. The actual date would be further in the past.